# Disable auto-ban and remove IP Ranges (Internet)

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, hmail-server

I want to set up `hMailServer` on Windows 7 with `VBScript` (.vbs). I know how to create domain and account with script since there has example online. But anybody know how to disable auto-ban and remove an IP range with `VBScript`? I didn't find any example about this online. Or does anybody know disable auto-ban and remove IP range from command line?

Answer (score 0):

IP range = security range

Settings >> Security Ranges >> Security Range
https://www.hmailserver.com/docs

And Autoban On /off is controlled by
Settings >> AutoBanOnLogonFailure which is a boolean, True is ON, False is OFF.